# Improve accuracy when solving a linear system where equations have coefficients ranging from E13 to E-18

Tags: python, sympy, floating-accuracy, equation-solving

i am doing some scientific calculations using python.I got into trouble when solving linear equations,where some coefficients are very large ~ E13 , some are very small ~E-69.It gives me a inaccurate solutions.

The equations,as folowing in the code, are very simple,just like `rate[0]=rate[1]=...=rate[6] rate[7]=0`.I use `slove` to get the solutions,but `rate[0]!=rate[1]=rate[2]=...`Although the most are right,but the physical meaning is totally wrong,which is unacceptable.rate[0]~rate[6] must be equal.

I tried some ways to promote the accuracy.

```
#convert float to symbols
kf_ = [symbols(str(k)) for k in kf_]
kb_= [symbols(str(k)) for k in kb_]
```

or

```
#convert float to decimal
kf_ = [Decimal(str(k)) for k in kf_]
kb_ = [Decimal(str(k)) for k in kb_]
```

But they both don't work.
I tried the same code on `matlab`,using `solve` or `vpasolve`in`symbolic math tool box`.The solutions are right.But for some reasons,the calutions must be done using python.
So my question is how to promote the accuracy?

```
from sympy import symbols , solve
from decimal import Decimal

#coeffcients   Some are very large ~ E13 , some are very small ~E-69
kf_= [804970533.1611289,
1.5474657692374676e-13,
64055206.72863516,
43027484.879109934,
239.58564380236825,
43027484.879109934,
0.6887097015872349,
43027484.879109934]

kb_=[51156022807606.22,
4.46863981338889e-18,
9.17599257631182,
8.862701377525092e-43,
4.203415587017237e-20,
2180151.4516747626,
5.590961781720337e-69,
0.011036598954049947]

#convert float to symbols , it takes quite a long time
#kf_ = [symbols(str(k)) for k in kf_]
#kb_= [symbols(str(k)) for k in kb_]
#or
#convert float to decimal
#kf_ = [Decimal(str(k)) for k in kf_]
#kb_ = [Decimal(str(k)) for k in kb_]

# define unkown
theta = list(symbols('theta1:%s' % (8 + 1)))

#define some expressions
rate=[0]*8
rate[0] = kf_[0] * theta[0] - kb_[0] * theta[1]
rate[1] = kf_[1] * theta[1] - kb_[1] * theta[2]
rate[2] = kf_[2] * theta[2] - kb_[2] * theta[3]
rate[3] = kf_[3] * theta[3] - kb_[3] * theta[4]
rate[4] = kf_[4] * theta[4] - kb_[4] * theta[5]
rate[5] = kf_[5] * theta[5] - kb_[5] * theta[6]
rate[6] = kf_[6] * theta[6] - kb_[6] * theta[0]
rate[7] = kf_[7] * theta[0] - kb_[7] * theta[7]

print('\n'.join(str(r) for r in rate))

#euqations
fun=[0]*8
fun[0]=sum(theta)-1
fun[1]=rate[0]-rate[1]# The coefficients kb[0] (~E13 )and kf[1] (~E-13) are merged
fun[2] = rate[1] - rate[2]
fun[3] = rate[2] - rate[3]
fun[4] = rate[3] - rate[4]
fun[5] = rate[4] - rate[5]
fun[6] = rate[5] - rate[6]
fun[7] = rate[7]

#solve
solThetaT=solve(fun,theta)
#print(solThetaT)
theta_=[solThetaT[t]  for t in theta]
#print(theta_)
rate_=[0]*8
for i in range(len(rate)):
    rate_[i]=rate[i].subs(solThetaT)

print('\n'.join(str(r) for r in rate_))

#when convert float to symbols
#for r in rate_:
    #print(eval(str(r)))
```

The result for rate[0]~rate[7]:

```
-1.11022302462516e-16
6.24587893889839e-28
6.24587893889839e-28
6.24587893889840e-28
6.24587893889840e-28
6.24587893222751e-28
6.24587895329296e-28
-3.81639164714898e-17
```

The most serious is rate[0] is negative and rate[6],which is supposed to be zero, has the largest absorbate value.

And the right solutions in matlab

```
 6.245878938898438e-28
 6.245878938898395e-28
 6.245878938898395e-28
 6.245878938898395e-28
 6.245878938898395e-28
 6.245878938898395e-28
 6.245878938898395e-28
                 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid any loss of precision in floating point arithmetics, recast the given coefficients as rationals. Assuming  `from sympy import Rational`, this is done with

```
kf_ = [Rational(x) for x in kf_]
kb_ = [Rational(x) for x in kb_]
```

Then use the code you have to solve the system and compute the rates. To display floating point numbers instead of giant rationals, use `evalf` method:

```
print('\n'.join(str(r.evalf()) for r in rate_))
```

prints

```
6.24587893889840e-28
6.24587893889840e-28
6.24587893889840e-28
6.24587893889840e-28
6.24587893889840e-28
6.24587893889840e-28
6.24587893889840e-28
0
```

Note: SymPy documentation recommends using [`linsolve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve) for linear systems, but you'd need to adapt the code to deal with the different return type of `linsolve`.

Also, a linear system with numeric coefficients can be solved directly by [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/doc/1.0.0/matrices.html#linear-equations) which allows setting an arbitrarily large precision of floating point computations.